# Android Accessory works only with MTP/PTP/USB Debugging on

Tags: android, android-debug

When using a rooted Nexus 7, The phone only identifies as an accessory when USB Debugging mode is on.  I don't have this issue with a cyanogen mod phone (both running 4.3).  How can I make the phone respond as an accessory when Debugging is turned off?

EDIT:

The issue is the Android tablet only connects when MTP or PTP `USB Computer connection` is on, or if USB Debuging is on.  It doesn't show up as an accessory at all otherwise.

SO - New question - Can you add an accessory type to the `USB Computer connection`, as I don't want the tablet to connect as neither MPT nor PTP? I especially don't want the device to have to be in debug mode for it to be identified.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my "galaxy s4 mini". I did the following and it works for me:

Note: It works for linux (Ubuntu's distribution).

Open your console and run the following command:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa: langdalepl / gvfs-mtp
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Reboot and ready.
I hope this helps